# NullReferenceException in ContentManager, XNA

Tags: xna, nullreferenceexception

I'm having a problem with NullReferenceException in XNA. I have 4 classes: Hero, Sprite, Fireball, Game1. Through debugging I see that problem occurs after my Fireball loads content through pipe

```
    class Fireball: Sprite
    {
        const int MAX_DISTANCE = 500;

        public bool Visible = false;

        Vector2 mStartPosition;
        Vector2 mSpeed;
        Vector2 mDirection;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager)
        {
            base.LoadContent(theContentManager, "Fireball");
            Scale = 0.3f;
        }
```

Then in my Sprite class I'm trying to load through ContentManager my texture

```
class Sprite
    {
        //The asset name for the Sprite's Texture
        public string AssetName;

        //The Size of the Sprite (with scale applied)
        public Rectangle Size;

        //The amount to increase/decrease the size of the original sprite. 
        private float mScale = 1.0f;

        //The current position of the Sprite
        public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0);

        //The texture object used when drawing the sprite
        private Texture2D myTexture;

        //Load the texture for the sprite using the Content Pipeline
        public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theAssetName)
        {
            myTexture = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
            AssetName = theAssetName;
            Source = new Rectangle(0, 0, myTexture.Width, myTexture.Height);
            Size = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(myTexture.Width * Scale), (int)(myTexture.Height * Scale)); ;
        }
```

And it gives me a NullReferenceException in myTexture = theContentManager.Load(theAssetName); line. Through debug report I see that the asset name has the "Fireball" in it, but the ContentManager itself gets null. What am I doing wrong? Since I am new in C# I would appreciate if somebody can tell me what lines should I add and where. If somebody needs a full project, it's here https://www.dropbox.com/s/1e353e834rggj40/test.rar Since it's a bit massive.

Comment: I ran the full project and it worked fine

Comment: I forgot to add! The loading of Fireball texture happens only when you click right Ctrl. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling LoadContent for fireball from Game1 wich means you have no ContentManager.
Added this to your Sprite class:

```
public static ContentManager Cm;
```

And then at the top of your LoadContent in Game1

```
Sprite.Cm = this.Content;
```

then it should work fine because you saved the ContentManager for later use in the Sprite class.